# Save StringBuilder contents into a SQL DB field

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stringbuilder, varbinarymax

I have some text in a String Builder Object in my ASP.NET page, I want to save it into a field in an SQL Server database. I am taking varBinary(max) for that, but not able to save it.

Please tell me which is the best way to do so?

Comment: In my asp.net page i am making a string builder to export data into text file, now i need to save that String into database (SQL SERVER). i am able to get string but not able to save into database, should i take another database field instead of VarBinary?

Comment: Please don't repeat your question as a comment: you can edit your question if you want to add more details. But it isn't clear what your problem is here: what does "not able to save it" mean? How are you trying to save it and what happens? Do you get errors and if so what are they? Can you show the code where you save the object? And it's usually a good idea to mention the version of SQL Server that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

take VARCHAR(MAX)

it may help you